# Provide multiple toolchain options in CMake

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I have an embedded project for ARM platform, specifically aarch64.

Up until now I was using Make. I recently set up CMake with no particular issues.
I moved to CMake because I was under the impression it was a more modern build tool that would have allowed a smarter configuration.

For example, I can compile my project using different toolchains (aarch64-elf-gcc-linaro, aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc,...) and I would like CMake to try if any of those are installed on the system and use whichever is found first by default.

Is this possible (or meant to)? I'd expect it to be an easy feat for the tool, but after searching for a while I can't seem to find the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make your CMake project to search for available tool-chains installed in your OS, choose one and compile your project. I also write a CMake program for ARM embedded project, because now it is universal transferable between different OS system Windows and Unix. On Linux there is [ARM ToolChain](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) installed and on Windows there is [Keil-MDK](http://www2.keil.com/mdk5). If you have different tool-chains to choose between, you can write CMake script which will find paths with command like [find_path()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_path.html#find-path) and then call correct "toolchianxx.cmake" script with right compiler flags for chosen compiler.

In your particular problem just use find_path commands and use hits to find installed compilers in "pre-set" known paths.